# App crashes when intent a new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops, onclicklistener

I am making a game on android and I wanted to use a loop in a `onClickListener` to display a dialog which is stored in `String.xml`

I set some code but the app crashes, there are no error in eclipse but I don't know what's wrong. So plz help check the code. I will show the code which I can run without crash(with `onClickListener` ,without the loop) and the wrong code which caused the crash(with the loop I wrote, I guess somethings wrong there)

The one that don't crash

```
package com.group5.littlered;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Scene1 extends Activity{

MediaPlayer wovleshowling;
MediaPlayer bgm;

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wtf);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }



        }
);

    //BGM
    bgm = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.unsettledthoughts);
    bgm.setLooping(true);
    bgm.start();

    //wovleshowling
    wovleshowling = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.wolveshowling);
    wovleshowling.setLooping(false);
    wovleshowling.start();

}

}
```

The one that crashed :

```
    package com.group5.littlered;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Scene1 extends Activity{

MediaPlayer wovleshowling;
MediaPlayer bgm;

int position = 0;
String [] conversation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scene1);
TextView frame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wtf);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (position < 6){

                String sentence = conversation[position];

            frame.setText(sentence + "");
            position ++ ;
            }
            }



        }
);

    //BGM
    bgm = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.unsettledthoughts);
    bgm.setLooping(true);
    bgm.start();

    //wovleshowling
    wovleshowling = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.wolveshowling);
    wovleshowling.setLooping(false);
    wovleshowling.start();





}

}
```

Comment: crash -> post stacktrace.

Comment: also, you posted twice the same class.

Comment: yah, but they are the same class, but the I can run the first one(without the loop I wrote by myself), the second one I can't run,its gonna crash

Comment: Did you add the activity to the manifest file?

Comment: check logcat view in eclipse. It would have a flood of red colored entries if you see a crash on screen.

Comment: `String [] conversation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scene1);` can't do that before onCreate is called.

Comment: `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` that neither.

Answer (score 0):

Please move

```
TextView frame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

inside onCreate() after setContentView call.

Since you haven't paste logs, I am assuming this is causing NullPointerException in your onClick() function.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the UI in onCreate(), So Bind TextView with xml in onCreate().

```
public class Scene1 extends Activity{

MediaPlayer wovleshowling;
MediaPlayer bgm;

int position = 0;
String [] conversation = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scene1);
TextView frame;

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     frame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);//this should be inside the onCreate() method
     //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene1);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wtf);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (position < 6){

                String sentence = conversation[position];

            frame.setText(sentence + "");
            position ++ ;
            }
            }



        }
);

    //BGM
    bgm = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.unsettledthoughts);
    bgm.setLooping(true);
    bgm.start();

    //wovleshowling
    wovleshowling = MediaPlayer.create(Scene1.this, R.raw.wolveshowling);
    wovleshowling.setLooping(false);
    wovleshowling.start();

}

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU ANYWAY, but it's not working I did exactly what you told me

Answer (score 0):

**TextView frame = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);**
must be inside *onCreate()* method,Becuase the method *findViewById()* called after app is created